Scroll looks harsh in static site Hero section with framer-motion scroll animations
In a personal site I have a Hero section with a couple images set to produce a parallax effect and a 3D model. The desired behavior is for the 3d model to animate before the parallax effect is animated, so I gave the section a 200vh (tailwind class h-hero) height and animated the images with framer-motion so the transformY initally counters the scroll distance, to accommodate for both these effects. But now the section looks rough on scroll as if the whole section was shifting with it. I haven't been able to pin-point the cause to a perfomance issue.
The page is deployed here
This is the code for my hero section component:
import { motion, useScroll, useTransform } from "framer-motion";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import Voyager from "./Voyager";
import Position from "./Position";

const Hero = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: ref,
    offset: ["start start", "end start"],
  })
  const layer1 = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["0vh", "200vh"]);
  const layer2 = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 0.5, 1], ["0vh", "100vh", "150vh"]);
  const layer3 = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 0.5, 1], ["0vh", "100vh", "100vh"]);
  const textY = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 0.5, 1], ["0vh", "100vh", "160vh"]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      className="relative top-0 w-full h-hero overflow-hidden grid"
    >
      <motion.div
        style={{ y: textY }}
        className="relative z-10 -mt-0"
      >
        <div className='parallax__content relative ml-4 top-[8%] sm:ml-8 sm:top-[10%] lg:top-[10%] w-full mx-auto lg:pl-[6rem] lg:pr-[6rem] xl:pl-[10rem] xl:pr-40 2xl:px-40 3xl:px-60 flex flex-col lg:flex-row lg:items-end'>
          <div className="flex-1 lg:mb-0">
            <h1 className='font-medium max-w-[80%] text-white text-[40px] sm:text-[38px] md:text-[50px] lg:text-[70px] 2xl:text-[120px] 3xl:text-[150px]'>
              SANTIAGO ZULUAGA
            </h1>
            <Position />
          </div>
          <div className="flex-1 flex justify-start lg:justify-center mt-4 sm:mt-14 lg:mt-10 2xl:mt-0">
            <div className='font-bold text-[25px] mt-8 lg:-mb-4 xl:mb-0 sm:text-[30px] md:text-[36px] 2xl:text-[46px] sm:leading-[40px] md:leading-[50px] 2xl:leading-[60px] streaky-glow max-w-sm 2xl:max-w-lg text-white text-left'>
              Passionate about <br/> science, technology and astronomy.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </motion.div>

      <motion.div
        className="absolute h-screen inset-0 z-0"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(./Layer1.png)`,
          backgroundPosition: "top",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          y: layer1,
          willChange: 'transform'
        }}
      />
      <motion.div
        className="absolute h-screen inset-0 z-20"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(./Layer2.png)`,
          backgroundPosition: "top",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          y: layer2,
          willChange: 'transform'
        }}
      />
      <motion.div
        className="absolute h-screen inset-0 z-30"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(./Layer3.png)`,
          backgroundPosition: "top",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          y: layer3,
          willChange: 'transform'
        }}
      />
      <Voyager />
    </div>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Hero)

And this is the code for the 3D model -- component:
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useScroll, useTransform } from "framer-motion";
import { motion } from "framer-motion-3d";

import voyagerModel from "../assets/3d/voyager.glb";
import Loader from "./Loader";

const Voyager = ({ scale, position }) => {
  const { scene } = useGLTF(voyagerModel);

  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll();
  const rotationX1 = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["0.3", "-1"]);
  const rotationY1 = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 0.2, 1], ["-0.8", "-1.6", "-10"]);
  const positionX = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 0.2, 1], [position[0], '0', '-3']);
  const positionY = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 0.2, 1], [position[1], '-2', '5']);
  const positionZ = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 0.2, 1], [position[2], '0', '0']);

  return (
    <motion.mesh position={[positionX, positionY, positionZ]} scale={scale} rotation={[rotationX1, rotationY1, 0]}>
      <primitive object={scene} />
    </motion.mesh>
  );
};

const Lights = () => {
  const directionalLightRef = useRef()
  const pointLightRef = useRef()
  const spotLightRef = useRef()
  const hemisphereLightRef = useRef()

  return (
    <>
      <directionalLight position={[2, 2, 2]} intensity={1} ref={directionalLightRef}/>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.3} />
      <pointLight position={[10, 0, 10]} intensity={2} ref={pointLightRef}/>
      <spotLight position={[-20, 0, 3]} angle={.15} penumbra={0} intensity={0.5} ref={spotLightRef}/>
      <hemisphereLight skyColor="#b1e1ff" groundColor="#000000" intensity={1} ref={hemisphereLightRef}/>
    </>
  )
}

const VoyagerCanvas = ({ scrollContaienr }) => {
  const [scale, setScale] = useState([2, 2, 2]);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState([0.2, -0.7, 0]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
        setScale([0.3, 0.3, 0.3]);
        setPosition([0, 3, -5]);
      } else if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        setScale([0.3, 0.3, 0.3]);
        setPosition([1.5, 5, -5]);
      } else if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
        setScale([0.33, 0.33, 0.33]);
        setPosition([2.5, 5, -7]);
      } else if (window.innerWidth < 1280) {
        setScale([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]);
        setPosition([3, 5.5, -10]);
      } else if (window.innerWidth < 1536) {
        setScale([0.66, 0.66, 0.66]);
        setPosition([3, 5, -10]);
      } else {
        setScale([1, 1, 1]);
        setPosition([6, 5, -15]);
      }
    };

    handleResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Canvas className={`!absolute w-full h-screen bg-transparent z-40`} camera={{ near: 0.1, far: 1000 }}>
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <Lights />
        <Voyager scale={scale} position={position} ref={scrollContaienr} />
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default React.memo(VoyagerCanvas);

